# Read variable from http context in spring controller

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc

Let me say i want retrieve some information from http context. In my thymeleaf page, I use somethinf like that:

```
<span th:text="${#httpServletRequest.getHeader('Accept-Language')}"></span>
```

in my thymeleaf processor, however, I use a code like that:

```
String language = arguments.getContext().getLocale().getLanguage();
String country = arguments.getContext().getLocale().getCountry();
```

How I can retriee this same information in my spring controller, implemented the way below?

```
  @RequestMapping("/insert_texto/{page}")
  public ModelAndView insert_texto(Model model, @PathVariable("page") String id)    {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would annotate the servlet request or context directly in your controller:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;

@RequestMapping("/insert_texto/{page}")
public ModelAndView insert_texto(Model model, @PathVariable("page") String id)  
{
    // use context
}
```

Or, if you prefer, pass `ServletContext` as a variable to your method:

```
@RequestMapping("/insert_texto/{page}")
public ModelAndView insert_texto(Model model, @PathVariable("page") String id, ServletContext context)  
{
    // use context
}
```

Comment: it worked, but do you know which attribute i should read to get the value i want (Accept-Language)? I mean, which parameter for context.getAttribute('...') - if this was the way to get what i want.